# Javascript password hashing for sending insecurely

Tags: javascript, authentication, hash, passwords

I want to send a password over HTTP.

Scenario:

1. User enters his username and password into a form.
2. Password is hashed and sent to the server with the username.
3. Server checks password hash and username and authenticates user. (the server doesn't know the plain text password either.)

If someone somehow intercepts the authentication message, he will obtain the hashed password and username, and he could potentially log in to that user's account. Essentially, the hashed password IS the password, according to the server.

Here's the thing: **I don't care.** It's rare enough that someone would have that data hijacked, and even so, it's not really a problem if your account gets stolen, you can just make a new one.

**The Question**: What is a good way to hash the user's password in JavaScript? The hash can't use random salt since it needs to be recognized by the server.

The only thing I am concerned about is the user's plain text password being found out if the message is intercepted. The reason being that the plain text password could also be used to compromise other services the person uses that may actually contain important information.

EDIT: to clarify, the question is mainly about what hashing algorithm to use, and if there is a lightweight library for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If security is actually not an issue, e.g. it's okay for people to compromise your system, and the only reason you want to salt the hash is to prevent the use of rainbow tables and the plaintext password from being determined, then do this:

- Compute a sufficently long salt for every password on the server, and store it on the server (just like how most systems typically stores the password in the DB)
- Send the salt to the user in plaintext
- Compute the salted hash and send back

If I'm thinking about this correctly, this will still prevent the use of rainbow tables.

Otherwise, just go with `https`? :P

Comment: i guess this is about as close an answer as i can get, what i ended up doing is just semi-giving up and using a fast hashing function and used the username as a salt for simplicity. The 'recommended' hash algorithms took several seconds on a mobile device.